# Simplify Powershell Where-Object

Tags: powershell, csv, where-clause

I have working `Import-Csv` statement that uses `Where-Object`

```
Import-Csv D:\Script\my.csv | Where-Object {$_.SourceIP -Like '10.251.22.11*' -Or $_.SourceIP -Like '10.251.22.*' -Or $_.DestinationIP -Like '10.251.22.11*' -Or $_.DestinationIP -Like '10.251.22.*'}
```

If I try to simplify the statement, it doesn't work

```
Import-Csv D:\Script\my.csv | Where-Object {($_.SourceIP -Like ('10.251.22.11*' -Or '10.251.22.*')) -Or ($_.DestinationIP -like ('10.251.22.11*' -Or '10.251.22.*'))}
```

Google is not helping :-(

Comment: `-like` accepts only a single string with wildcards. See `help about_Operators` for details. There is no `-or` for `-like`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of -like, use -match in this case.

```
Import-Csv D:\Script\my.csv | Where-Object {$_.SourceIP -match '^10\.251\.22\.*' -or $_.DestinationIP -match '^10\.251\.22\.*'}
```

Also, 10.251.22.* will match 10.251.22.11*, so you can combine them.

Comment: *Instead of -like, use -match*: I does not think that OP want to match this `123.210.251.225` address by this `10.251.22.*` pattern (`'123.210.251.225' -match '10.251.22.*'` returns true).

Comment: @PetSerAl Good catch, thanks. Added the '^' character to indicate start of string.

Comment: You also need to do something with dots, as them means any char, rather than literal dot, for example you matching to `10.251.225.123`. At least you should use literal dot at the end of pattern `^10.251.22\.`.

Comment: Presuming those dots are a part of an IP address, she should just escape them.  Thanks

Comment: You still matching to `10.251.225.123`, as you apply `*` (*zero* or more) to last dot.

Comment: Decided to leave that one up to her, since she's got the * in the OP.  Thanks for the help